# A framework for real time messaging between a C++ App and an Xamarin Forms App

Tags: c#, c++, networking, xamarin, rabbitmq

I should implement a communication between a C++ Application and a mobile application developed using Xamarin Forms.

The Xamarin Application is targeted to Android, iOS and Windows.

The communication between the Xamarin Forms Application and the C++ one should be done in real time.

I tried to implement this ZeroMQ but we don't have a PCL for Xamarin. I search a lot for a solution but I did not find.

Is there a framework that can implement a real time communication between a C++ App and an Xamarin Forms App that targets Android, iOS and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm making the assumption that you are referring to "real-time" communication between the apps)

I would suggest using something like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) for the communication. They do seem to have a [C++ client](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp), and they support Xamarin. There may be other real-time communication libraries that support both.

I have used SignalR in a Xamarin application, albeit, I was using a pre-Alpha version of SignalR(version 0.5.2 from years ago), but it worked great and continues to work great for our use-case.

Comment: Thank you, +1. But It doesn't suceed to install as my project target Android. iOS and Windows.

Comment: I reedited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Did you get an error when installing the nuget packages? SignalR supports all 3 of those mobile platforms.